# How to get logonserver name in AD domain programatically

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory

A host which part of Active directory domain does authentication from the logon server (domain controller).

LOGONSERVER env var has its value.

C:>echo %LOGONSERVER%
\PUN5OPSDIRPIN01

Is there any API using which I can retrieve this value?

Comment: This could swing either way, on Stackoverflow or here.  I would propose that we keep it here because of the usefulness in scripting sysadmin tasks.

Answer (score 10):

Nearly every language or framework will have a method that will let you retrive the values of environment variables.  .NET, Powershell, Java...  What are you coding in?

C#:
`System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable ()`

Powershell:
`$env:<name of env variable>`, so for example `$env:logonserver`

WMI (using VBS):
`Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery(”Select * from Win32_Environment”)`

Java:
`System.getenv("LOGONSERVER")`

Comment: Well played, sir

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to retrieve that from the client, you could query "HKCU:\Volatile Environment\LOGONSERVER" or env:LOGONSERVER.